# Software Updater offers new updates even though computer has been offline

Tags: 14.04, updates, security

My computer was offline for a night executing some python scripts. My wifi was turned off and I had disabled networking completely. In the morning I found the Software Updater offering me new updates to be installed. When I clicked install, updater warned me that this requires installation of untrusted packages. The computer was offline the entire time. Should I be worried that something nasty e.g. a malicious attack had occurred during the night or before I went offline? My distribution is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: What did you do to disable the networking?

Comment: From wifi icon on the upper right --> clicked Enable networking so that all networking is disabled.

Comment: As mentioned in [db429's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/847095/602680), it is possible that your system was unable to verify the validity of packages that were already marked for upgrade. Basically, just run the `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` commands to manually verify the validity of the updates. After that, the updates should be fine. I wouldn't worry about any security issues.

Answer (score 3):

My assumption is two things happened during that night:

a) your system automaticly ran `apt update` issued by  `aptd` but didn't find anything - due to no connection and

b) previously downloaded packages - which do not regard as security updates - where offered to be updated - as setup in `System Settings - Applications & Updates - Updates`.

This combination lead to those packages being untrusted, as there are no current hashes for them.
Manually checking for new updates by either running `Update-Manger` (found in your applications or `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` from a terminal should solve this

**To be sure nothing else happened**, i would check my source-lists and DNS-settings, if everythig is as it should do one of the above mentioned options

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guessed something similar myself. However, what dazzles me is that the Software & Updates settings are set so that _both_ security and other updates should be displayed immediately. I did not receive any such notification before going offline.

Comment: hmm .. i believe this can also happen, when the last update failed. i know this also happens when the last update is very old.